# i need help my coding for my fyp

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

how my coding works = 1 rfid card detect on first rfid reader and 2 rfid card detect on second rfid reader after that servo go to 90

my second rfid not detect

this is my coding

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo  myservo;
int pos = 0;
int angle = 0;
int angle11 = 0;

#define RST_PIN2           8          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN           9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN2          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above



MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN2 );   // Create MFRC522 instance.
MFRC522 mfrc522_2(SS_PIN2, RST_PIN2);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

 
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();        // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
  mfrc522_2.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();
   myservo.attach(5);
 



}
void loop() 
 {

// Look for new cards

if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {

return;

}

 // Select one of the cards

if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

return;

}

// Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called

mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

  delay(1000);
  // Look for new cards

  if ( ! mfrc522_2.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {

    return;

  }
  // Select one of the cards

  if ( ! mfrc522_2.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

    return;

    mfrc522_2.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

  }

 
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "09 99 55 B2") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
 {
String content= "1";
  byte letter;
  for (byte ii = 0; ii < mfrc522_2.uid.size; ii++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522_2.uid.uidByte[ii] < 0x10 ? " 0" : "1 ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522_2.uid.uidByte[ii], HEX);
     content.concat(String (mfrc522_2.uid.uidByte[ii] < 0x10 ? " 0" : "1 "));
     content.concat(String (mfrc522_2.uid.uidByte[ii], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "09 99 55 B3") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
 

      myservo.write(angle); delay(3000);
   for(angle = 0; angle > 90; angle11) 
    myservo.write(angle11);           
    delay(3000); 
    
    myservo.write(angle11); delay(3000);
   for(angle = 90; angle11 > 0; angle) 
    myservo.write(angle);           
    delay(3000); 
    }

 else  
 {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    delay(3000);
    
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Please explain more and with good english. If you are not good enough in english, you can ask someone, who can write english better.

Comment: change your logic a bit  ... use flags ... pseudo code `if card_1_is_present and card_1_is_read, then raise flag_1`   .... do not exit, do not stop, do not do anything more than setting the value of flag_1 .... next do the same thing for card_2 flag_2 ......... next, check flag_1 and flag_2 ... proceed with program if both are raised

Answer (score 1):

Right at the start of your loop you have this (and other similar constructs):

```cpp
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
}
```

That means that if no new card is present on reader 1 then the rest of the loop is ignored. Nothing else can happen.

You need to restructure your whole program so that it works in the complete opposite way - instead of saying "If there's no card do nothing" you should say "If there is a card then do something".